# GC.Collect call and OutOfMemory

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

When I call GC.Collect all works fine. But if I comment this call, I time from time receive OutOfMemory. Looks very strange.
How to find this bug ?

Additional info
Application sulution has some projects that have references to different frameworks from 2.0 to 4.0
Aplication is a windows forms application, devexpress is used.

Comment: more information about your code would be helpfull, i think

Comment: maybe you should tell us where the exception is thrown...

Comment: usualy exception is thrown on new + ctor call.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't localize the place and therefore I can't show the code because it is about 50 MB of size

Comment: Damn, profiler gets hanged on this project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely variants:

1. Large Object Heap fragmentation. In the application is used very big amount of collections of big size up to million elements, such as HashSet, Dictionary and etc. All of them call Array.Resize from time to time. So, GC.Collect does not solve the probem, just slows down the fragmentation.
2. unmanaged code

Edited:
3. System.Drawing tends to throw OOM exception in some cases

Answer (score 1):

You probably forget to dispose an object. Do you use any databases or other external resources?

Comment: No, I don't. The thing where an exception is thrown is related to devexpress and System.Drawing

Comment: That is where you use new memory (a lot), not where you allocate it and not released the memory. Dev express probably is not the cause of you memory problem.

Comment: I'm allocating a lot of pure clr objects in this place and OOM is usualy thrown on any ctor + new

Answer (score 1):

If you have to call GC.Collect then something is wrong. You usually should not need to call the garbage collector.

1. Try a memory profiler. This will show you how many objects of what type consume your heap.
2. Check your unmanaged ressources. Every unmanaged resource has to be managed by a class implementing IDispoable in conjunction with a finalizer.

Comment: Yes, I know, that something is wrong, but how profiler helps me ? there are millions of objects of many types :-(

Comment: Well, thats why you have to us e a profiler. The job of a profiler is to make this mass of objects interpretable for you.

Comment: I don't use any self made classes with unmanaged resources. All that I've got is Devexpress, pure clr objects and system.drawing

Answer (score 0):

A common approach to debug memory leaks in .net is to use the [SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bb190764.aspx)-Extension (you'll find some tutorials like [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/03/11/where-s-your-leak-at-using-windbg-sos-and-gcroot-to-diagnose-a-net-memory-leak.aspx) if you do some research) or to use a memory profiler, like [this](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) one. Maby you just forget to release (dispose) some unmanaged ressources?

Answer (score 0):

I would try debugging managed memory issues with the [CLR profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273).

Additionally, why are you calling GC.Collect() yourself? This is usually an anti-pattern.

Comment: Yes, I agree. That is why I asked the question on SO :-)